# Drag rows out of iTunes into Cocoa App

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, itunes, nstableview

How does one accept dragged rows from iTunes in a Cocoa Application ?

I have two objects in my application that accept Drag and Drop: an NSTableView and a custom view.  Both recognize files dragged from the finder, but neither recognize rows dragged from iTunes.

Comment: What exactly do you want from the iTunes rows? The media, the titles, ...

Comment: filepath.  I have the answer, but I can't post it for another 5 hours due to my measly reputation score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's the answer.  This will handle dragging things from iTunes, as well as dragging files from the finder.  What you get is a list of filepaths.  "sender" is the guy who has the dragging pasteboard.  The short answer is that "com.apple.pasteboard.promised-file-url" is the key that you need from the iTunes paste.

```
NSMutableArray *paths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
NSArray *pasteboardTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"com.apple.pasteboard.promised-file-url", @"public.file-url", nil];
for(NSPasteboardItem *item in [[sender draggingPasteboard] pasteboardItems]) {
  NSString *urlString = nil;
  for(NSString *type in pasteboardTypes) {
    if([[item types] containsObject:type]) {
      urlString = [item stringForType:type];
      break;
    }
  }
  if(urlString) {
    NSString *path = [[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] path];
    [paths addObject:path];
  }
}
NSLog(@"Pasted Paths: %@", paths);
```